# VS2012 Error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, sfml

I received the error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)" after attempting to run my exe file of my C++ SFML 32-bit program I built in Visual Studio 2012. I statically linked the SFML dlls in my project, but incorporated the following dlls along with my program:

```
libsndfile-1.dll
openal32.dll
msvcp110.dll
msvcp110d.dll
msvcr110.dll
msvcr110d.dll
```

What is the problem?

Comment: msvcr110d.dll - this is for debug builds. Try to install MSVC++ 2012 redistributables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The actual error code that you encountered is `0xC000007B`. That is the [NTSTATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) error code `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. That error arises, almost invariably, because the application is 32 bit and attempted to load a 64 bit module, or vice versa. In your case, you state that your application is 32 bit, so it seems that it is attempting to link to a 64 bit DLL. Use a tool like Dependency Walker to diagnose the module which has the wrong bitness.

I don't understand why you are distributing both release and debug versions of the MSVC runtime. You only need one, and that one should be the release versions. The files that end `d` are the debug versions. You are not permitted to redistribute them.

Comment: @user Are you still stuck?

Comment: I was using the 64 bit version of the msvcp110.dll instead of the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 2):

Error code `0xC000007B` can also result if you run an application that has  erroneously been statically linked with a .lib file that is an import library corresponding to a .dll (as opposed to a .lib file that is a static library). If you want to know more about the differences between a static library and an import library, see  [Why are LIB files beasts of such a duplicitous nature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421693/why-are-lib-files-beasts-of-such-a-duplicitous-nature)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem yesterday. Then I installed the Redistributable setup for VS i.e. vc_redist.x86 for 32-bit machine, after that application start running. You can use either 32-bits or 64-bits setup according your machine.

May it'll help you.
Thanks